# Not getting current IP address in my oracle database

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-11g-r2, installation

I have installed Oracle database in my local machine and my local machine IP address is - 192.168.1.55 but in Toad its showing different

```
SQL> SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') FROM dual;
SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')
----------------------------------------------------------
127.0.0.1

SQL>
```

For that I restarted Database but still it's showing the same.What changes need to do for reflecting current IP in the Database.

Comment: Which IP address do you want? The database server or the client? Your query returns the IP address of the client. Do you have a static IP address set?

Comment: All machines also have 127.0.0.1 as the loopback adapter, so Oracle is correct

Comment: I installed both oracle server and client on same local machine and It's static IP-192.168.

Comment: In your connection properties you set 192.168.1.55 or "localhost"?

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't make the change "in the database".  The database does not know or care about IP addresses at all.  As others have said, sys_context is showing properties of the client connection.

Comment: @AntonChekmarev in my connection properties it was localhost that's it's showing IP-127.0.0.1.Now I reset as same machine IP-192.168.1.55 then it's showing IP-192.168.1.55.Problem is resolved.Thanks Anton,alazs,Phil and EdStevens for valuable reply.

Answer (score 1):

`SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')` returns the ip-address of the client currently connected to the server. 
In your case your toad is connected to Oracle server using loopback ip address(localhost). 
I dont have toad demostrate it but I have tested it in my linux machine.

```
[oracle@testsrv Desktop]$ sqlplus sys/oracle@192.168.1.50/orcl as sysdba

SQL> select sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192.168.1.50

SQL> exit

[oracle@testsrv Desktop]$ sqlplus sys/oracle@localhost/orcl as sysdba

SQL> select sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
127.0.0.1

SQL>
```